# Jenkins . Git Client Plugin [I can't download it]

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I uninstalled jenkins from my windows my machine. Then I reinstalled it, but now when I try to download the `Git Client Plugin` it tells me it failed at it and shows me the next exception.

```
hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to download from http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/git-client/1.11.1/git-client.hpi (redirected to: http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/git-client/1.11.1/git-client.hpi)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:791)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1138)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1298)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1116)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:104)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/git-client/1.11.1/git-client.hpi
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:756)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/git-client/1.11.1/git-client.hpi
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getHeaderFieldLong(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLengthLong(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLength(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:755)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution, the problem was that the last realease was taken down, but somehow jenkins keeps pointing to it as availible even on its wiki. I downloaded a previous version of the plugin and installed it manually.